# Improve join speed on timestamp range on postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've a query that joins two tables:

- table 1 `data` has a timestamp column
- table 2 `orders` has start and end timestamp columns

On table 1 I've an index on the timestamp column and on table 2 I've an index on start|end (in this order). Everything works fine and is fast when I simply join them like `FROM d JOIN o ON d.timestamp > o.start_ts AND d.timestamp <= o.end_ts`

The problem is that when an order is not completed,  the `end_ts` is null so I need to change my join to `d.timestamp <= COALESCE(o.end_ts, null)`, from the explain I can see that now the index scan includes a `filter` section that makes it way slower (from 1s to 14s).

The query I'm currently using is:

```
SELECT *
FROM data pd
JOIN orders o ON pd.timestamp > o.start_time AND pd.timestamp <= COALESCE(o.end_time, now())
WHERE pd.machine_id = 19 AND pd.name = 'somevalue' AND pd.timestamp > '2019-09-15 22:00:00' AND pd.timestamp <= '2019-09-22 21:59:59.999'
```

the explain is

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.72..162190.37 rows=1647921 width=187) (actual time=2.589..18590.362 rows=7775 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=44030111 read=3348
  I/O Timings: read=20.984
  ->  Index Scan using data_timestamp_machine_id_name_unique on data pd  (cost=0.43..20237.60 rows=1730 width=81) (actual time=0.055..50.357 rows=7713 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (("timestamp" > '2019-09-15 22:00:00-07'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" <= '2019-09-22 21:59:59.999-07'::timestamp with time zone) AND (machine_id = 19) AND ((name)::text = 'weight'::text))
        Buffers: shared hit=5132 read=3216
        I/O Timings: read=20.591
  ->  Index Scan using orders_machine_id_idx on orders o  (cost=0.29..72.52 rows=953 width=106) (actual time=2.401..2.401 rows=1 loops=7713)
        Index Cond: ((machine_id = 19) AND (pd."timestamp" > start_time))
        Filter: (pd."timestamp" <= COALESCE(end_time, now()))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 7108
        Buffers: shared hit=44024979 read=132
        I/O Timings: read=0.393
Planning Time: 0.191 ms
Execution Time: 18591.568 ms
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: @Abelisto same result, both timings and explain are the same

Comment: Try `..ON d.timestamp > o.start_ts AND d.timestamp <= o.end_ts UNION ALL .. ON pd.timestamp > o.start_time AND  o.end_time is null`

Comment: @Serg that works perfectly for a simple query like this, but in a query with joins and group clauses an UNION ALL would make the query much longer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the cases where [range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) come in handy as they treat NULL values properly.

Create an index on the range:

```
CREATE INDEX orders_range ON orders using gist (tsrange(start_time,end_time,'(]'));
```

Then use the same range definition in the join condition

```
SELECT *
FROM data pd
JOIN orders o ON pd.timestamp <@ ts_range(o.start_time, o.end_time, '(]')
WHERE pd.machine_id = 19 
  AND pd.name = 'somevalue' 
  AND pd.timestamp > '2019-09-15 22:00:00' AND pd.timestamp <= '2019-09-22 21:59:59.999'
```

---

Unrelated, but: I would use `pd.timestamp < '2019-09-22 22:00:00'` instead of a `<=` operator with a timestamp that is a few milliseconds before 22:00:00

Comment: I agree on the unrelated part, regarding the index, why gist?

Comment: @alex88: because only a GIST index supports the `<@` operator on ranges

Comment: your `start_time`, `end_time` columns could be replaced with a single range column as well - that way you would never need to worry about how to represent "unbounded" ranges as it is part of the column value itself.

Comment: that would make sense, I just need to check how the db library we're using supports it

Comment: I think the only downside of this, is that we can't easily change the bounds inclusion/exclusion on the query without changing the index

Comment: @alex88: but don't they always mean the same? It sounds strange to me that the rule for inclusive/exclusive bounds change randomly. But if you do need that,  a single range column where that information is stored with the value itself would solve the problem. The index then only needs to mention the column, not create a new range.

Comment: It actually changes only when on the other side of the relation the value is an aggregate and is related to the previous or next minute, but that's just a matter of standardizing it

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the special handling of NULLs by using `NOT(negated_condition)`. (but the `Infinity` solution is cleaner,IMO)

---

```
SELECT *
FROM data pd
JOIN orders o ON pd.timestamp > o.start_time 
        AND NOT(pd.timestamp > o.end_time )
WHERE pd.machine_id = 19 
        AND pd.name = 'somevalue'
        AND pd.timestamp > '2019-09-15 22:00:00'
        AND pd.timestamp <= '2019-09-22 21:59:59.999'
        ;
```

Comment: This looks good too, I haven't tried it yet to see how the query explain handles it but it might avoid having functions in the index

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `incognito` on IRC I've found a viable solution, create an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX orders_timestamps ON orders (start_time,coalesce(end_time,'infinity'));
```

and change the query to `pd.timestamp <= COALESCE(o.end_time, 'infinity')`.
This way I still have my nullable value and I have an indexed value that I can use, since I couldn't index the `NOW()` because it's variable

Comment: This is not equivalent to the stated requirements. More rows could be returned.

Comment: @Serg why? In my case when order end is NULL means it's not terminated, so infinity would work because it's always greater than NOW()

Comment: "infinity .. always greater than NOW()" means more rows could be returned. Probably you need to refine the question concerning your usage of `now()`. Was it a requiement or something else?

Comment: @Serg I think it's just because the `data` table never has data from the future,  so there won't be any data with a timestamp greater than `NOW()`